# Mssql перенос 2017 експресс в 2008 r2 standart

Tags: sql-server, express, sql-server-2008

Как базу mssql 2017 конвертировать в версию 2008 r 2?

Comment: Какие объекты (ну кроме таблиц) имеются в БД? Операция - одноразовая?

Comment: В бд только таблийы с данными

Comment: Ну тогда... Скрипты создания - экспортировать, адаптировать, импортировать. Данные - выгрузить в CSV, загрузить в готовые таблицы из CSV, обращая внимания на порядок загрузки зависимых данных. Всё.

Comment: Как вариант можно использовать программу, на подобие SQL-delta